# Food cooked on Shabbas for Pikuach Nefesh

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cooking-bishul, motzei-shabbos, dechiya-superseding

What is the status of the leftover food cooked for a person who was critically ill on Shabbas? Halachicly one is allowed to cook food on Shabbas and eat it if their life is in jeopardy.  However, let's say after Shabbas the person is not critical anymore. May he eat the leftover food from that cooking? Do we say it's assur to him since he cooked it on Shabbas, or do we say that he cooked it beheter (with permission) so the food is considered mutar?

I was thinking of the gemara in Chullin 17a, about Rav Yirmiya's question about whether pieces of meat that had nechirah (piercing of the pipes-non shechita) done to it in the midbar (which was considered kosher) was kosher once they crossed over to Eretz Yisrael where the Torah then prohibited nechirah altogether. The gemara ends off by saying teiku, but I was wondering if my case is similar, or it's more of a hutrah-dechuya case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer:

- If a Jew cooked the food, then yes, it may be eaten.
- If a non-Jew cooked the food it's a debate amongst the Poskim.

Sources:

The Kitzur Shulchan in 92:9 [סימן צב - דין חולה שיש בו סכנה ודין אנוס לעברה.](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0091_L2) addresses this:

> **סעיף ט'**:
>   הַמְבַשֵּׁל בְּשַׁבָּת בִּשְׁבִיל חוֹלֶה, אָסוּר לְבָרִיא לְאָכְלוֹ בַשַׁבָּת, אֲבָל לְמוֹצָאֵי שַׁבָּת מֻתָּר מִיָּד גַּם לְבָרִיא אִם בִּשְּׁלוֹ יִשְֹרָאֵל, וְעַיֵּן לְעֵיל סִימָן לח סָעִיף ט (שיח). ‏

"Food that was cooked (permissibly) for an ill person on Shabbat may not be eaten by a healthy person on Shabbat."

"However, after Shabbat is over, it is permitted to everybody, immediately. (No need to wait *the time it takes to make it*)."

The Kitzur then refers you to 38:9 [סימן לח - הלכות פת ובשולי עובד כוכבים](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0037_L2) where he states:

> **סעיף ט'**:
>   עוֹבֵד כּוֹכָבִים שֶׁבִּשֵּׁל בְּשַׁבָּת בִּשְׁבִיל חוֹלֶה, הַתַּבְשִׁיל אָסוּר בְּמוֹצָאֵי שַׁבָּת, אֲפִלּוּ לְהַחוֹלֶה אִם אֶפְשָׁר בְּתַבְשִׁיל אַחֵר (עַיֵּן פר"ח יו"ד סוֹף סִימָן קי"ג), וּבְכֵלִים יֵשׁ לְהַתִּיר אַחַר מֵעֵת לְעֵת. ‏

"Food that was cooked for an ill person by a non-Jew on Shabbat may not be eaten after Shabbat. "

"Not even the ill person may continue to eat this food if there is other food available."

"Regarding the dishes that the food was cooked in by a non-Jew, they may be used again after 24 hours" (after the hot food was removed from them, presumably).

However, the Rema in Shulchan Aruch Yoreh De'ah 133:16 [סימן קיג - דיני בשולי עובדי כוכבים](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01976_part_17.html#HtmpReportNum0001_L2) argues and permits the food cooked by a non-Jew for an ill person to be eaten by everybody after Shabbat, and thus the dishes too are Kosher.

> הגה: עוֹבֵד כּוֹכָבִים שֶׁבִּשֵּׁל לְחוֹלֶה בְּשַׁבָּת, מֻתָּר לְמוֹצָאֵי שַׁבָּת, אֲפִלּוּ  לְבָרִיא, וְאֵין בּוֹ מִשּׁוּם בִּשּׁוּלֵי עוֹבְדֵי כּוֹכָבִים, דְּכָל כְּהַאי גַּוְנָא הֶכֵּרָא אִכָּא‏

Though many Poskim argue with him, as the Be'er Heitev (in 19) (ibid) mentions.

> **יט)** לבריא. והט''ז חולק על דין זה ואוסר לבריא במ''ש ואפי' לחולה עצמו אינו מותר אלא בשעת הדחק עכ''ל (ועיין בנה''כ דמיקל בזה) (ואחרונים חלקו וחלילה להקל ואפילו לחולה עצמו אינו מותר אלא בשבת ולמוצאי שבת חוזר לאיסור וכ''ש לבריא וכ' ט''ז וראיה מסי' קי''ב סעיף ח' דבמקום שאין פלטר מצוי התירו של בע''ה וזה ודאי דאחר שיבא למקום שיהא פלטר מצוי כו' ולא אוכל להבין הלא המחבר גופיה כ' בפי' כך בסעיף ד' ע''ש ול''נ להוכיח דאסור לאוכלו במ''ש כדאיתא בגמ' השוחט לחולה בשבת מותר לבריא באומצא אבל המבשל לחולה אסור לבריא גזירה שמא ירבה בשבילו אם כן הכי נמי אם יהא מותר לחולה למ''ש שמא ירבה בשבילו וק''ל):‏